# Functional equation $f(f(x)-x)=f(f(x))$

Tags: functional-equations

Consider the following functional equation:

$$f(f(x)-x)=f(f(x))$$

where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Obviously $f(x)$ cannot be inverted.

One solution is $f(x) = k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

Are there any other solution?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $f$? Is it continuous, differentiable, anything?

Comment: No there is no assumption, but if with an assumption we can get a partial result it would be nice.

Comment: Note that if $f$ has a fixed point, then it is $f(0)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define $f(x)$ by

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\ \ \,1&\text{if $x<0$} \\
\ \ \,0&\text{if $x=0$} \\
-1&\text{if $x>0$} \\
\end{cases}
$$
The equation holds for $x=0$ as $f(f(0)-0)=f(f(0))$.

The equation holds for $x>0$ as $f(f(x)-x)=f(-1-x)=1=f(-1)=f(f(x))$.

The equation hold for $x<0$ as $f(f(x)-x)=f(1-x)=-1=f(1)=f(f(x))$.

Comment: Thank you. This can be generalized with two arbitrary constant values, one positive and one negative, instead of 1 and -1, respectively.

Comment: Note also that the value at 0 is completely arbitrary.